# Use ESP-IDF components from outside project directory

Tags: c, cmake, arduino, esp32, esp-idf

I have multiple IDF projects and many of them use the same components. Instead of having a copy of the components in each project's directory, I want to place all the components in a global directory and use them in all my projects.
I'm using ESP-IDF v.4.4.4 in VSCode.
Here is the structure I want:

```
main_directory
|
|__global_components
|  |__component1
|  |__component2
|  |__component3
|
|__project1
|  |__CMakeLists.txt
|  |__sdkconfig
|  |__main/
|  |  |__CMakeLists.txt
|  |  |__src.c
|  |__build
|
|__project2
|  |__CMakeLists.txt
|  |__sdkconfig
|  |__main/
|  |  |__CMakeLists.txt
|  |  |__src.c
|  |__build
|
|__project3
```

This is what the `CMakeLists.txt` file in my project directory looks like:

```
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(esp32_project)
```

How will I have to change this file?

This is what the `CMakeLists.txt` in my project/main directory looks like:

```
idf_component_register(
    SRCS "crypto.cpp" "image.cpp" "main.cpp"
    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
)
```

Will I have to change this file too?
Thanks for the help. If I am approaching this in the wrong way and there is a better way to manage the problem I would love to know.

I tried `set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS $(PROJECT_PATH)/../global_components/)` but that did not work.